# Создать список из нескольких строк

Tags: python, list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] После некоторых манипуляций с большим списком я получаю нужные мне данные в таком виде:

```
data
print (data):

TABLE
CHAIR
SOFA 
WALL
```

Типы данных:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Нужно просто-напросто сделать из них список:

```
mylist
[TABLE, CHAIR, SOFA, WALL]
```

Почему то у меня и

```
mylist = [h for h in data]
```

и

```
mylist = []
mylist.append (data)
```

Не выдают желанного результата, а делают списки из каждого слова по отдельности, а внутри них разбивают каждую букву и разделяют их запятыми! Как сделать нормальный список со словами (str) внутри?

```
print(repr(data))
'TABLE'
'CHAIR'
'SOFA'
'WALL'
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, покажите `print(repr(data))`

Comment: Опять ничего не понял, `print(repr(data))` никак не может вывести то, то вы написали. Покажите скриншот вывода

Comment: Что непонятного в том, что data - это несколько слов. Из них нужно сделать список. Обычный список из слов, разделенных запятой.

Comment: «Несколько слов» — очень расплывчатое понятие, которое может охватывать кучу типов. Причём `str` — это **не** несколько слов, это массив символов, поэтому или data имеет тип не str, или вы что-то не договариваете. `repr` строки никак не может вывести результат в несколько строк (четыре, как вы показали) — repr всегда даёт ровно одну строку без переносов. Покажите скриншот вывода `print(repr(data))`, а лучше дайте [mcve], потому что непонятно вообще ничего.

Comment: Тем более что вы в своём вопросе показали два способа создания списка, которые точно рабочие. Почему они у вас не работают — непонятно, покажите весь необходимый код для воспроизведения проблемы, чтобы можно было ответить что-то внятное

Comment: Вот, вы всё-таки не договорили о существовании цикла. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = []
for h in a:
    q = h + 'LED'
    mylist.append(q)
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Получилось вот так: ['GASLED'] ['USDTLED']..   все слова по отдельности стали списками..

Comment: Не может такого получиться так из моего кода. Проверяйте, правильно ли вы его переписали.

Comment: @Кирилл вот смотрите, всё работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35rzl.png

Comment: Неверно у вас на скриншоте. Исходные данные - это не а, a q!

Comment: @Кирилл Тогда я вынужден повторить ещё раз: приведите [mcve] с вашим неработающим кодом. Я переписал в свой ответ код с вашего скриншота — **он работает, и исходные данные в вашем же скриншоте были именно a.** Если вы наврали в своём скриншоте — пожалуйста, прекратите врать и покажите настоящий код, если желаете получить-таки помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Непонимаю в чем может быть проблема, вроде все просто.

> Обычный список из слов, разделенных запятой

```
data = data.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашей переменной `data` вероятно только одна строка, в которой слова отделённые специальным симболом `\n` - переходом на новую строку:

```
data = 'TABLE\nCHAIR\nSOFA\nWALL'
print(data)
```

> ```
> TABLE
> CHAIR
> SOFA
> WALL
> ```

Тогда вы можете использовать метод `split()` для его перевода на список:

```
mylist = data.split()
print(mylist)
```

> ```
> ['TABLE', 'CHAIR', 'SOFA', 'WALL']
> ```